# how to select 1 number out of an array?

Tags: arrays, if-statement

I wanted to select a 1 number out of an array, for an if statement? how would I go about do that?

For example ive got 6 numbers in an array and i wanted to select number 3 to carry out an if statement.

Thanks

Comment: Which programing language?

Comment: Also, if the array contained numbers `4, 2, 6, 2, 3, 8`, are you looking for a way to get the number which is in the index 3 (2) or do you want to know in which index the number 3 is (4)?